# Add Custom CSS to system list.aspx

Tags: 2013

I am trying to add a custom CSS file to a system list.aspx page to override the position of some elements on the page. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint Designer open your list.aspx page and add the following right below the very last link element, if any exist.

```
<link href="MyStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Is it really as simple as this? I thought there would of had to be some Sharepoint markup etc?

Comment: @Csharper nope should be pretty straight forward when it comes to CSS. Be careful to leave all of the other page code intact. As an alternative you could also use a content editor webpart (CEWP) and add your css to it. This will keep you out of SPD altogether. See this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/40e97e/content-editor-web-part-and-css-tricks/

Comment: Ok i tried that and SharePoint designer is giving me an error saying content cannot exist outside of script of asp:content tags, i try inside a script tag and receive the same error, any ideas, sorry if i sound like a numpty im currently deep diving SP2013.

Comment: @Csharper try right clicking the file and selecting "Edit in advanced mode" like described here: http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-designer-2010-edit-in.html

Comment: Hi, i am in advanced mode, the file is actually called flat.aspx inside Community Discussion which displays a topic, if that helps?

Comment: @Csharper Try my alternative method I mentioned using the CEWP

Comment: I haven't had chance to test this yet but i will do over the next few days.